# Selecting Rows from one table based on conditions in two separate tables

Tags: mysql, database

I've tried using joins and wherein statements for the following but I either get a timeout because it's taking too long to run or I get duplicate column name error.

I have 3 tables: 
A, B, C
I'd like to create a table consisting of rows from A based on constraints in B and C. So The row in A has to fulfill a condition in B OR C:

(A.ID = B.ID and A.PURCHASE = B.PURCHASE) OR (A.ID = C.ID AND A.PURCHASE = C.PURCHASE).

I've been using mysql for around... a week and this is the closest I've gotten(it hangs):

```
CREATE TABLE D
SELECT T1.* 
FROM TABLE A AS T1, TABLE B AS T2, TABLE B AS T3
JOIN T2, T3 ON ((T1.CUSTOMER_ID = T2.CUSTOMER_ID AND T1.DAY_ID = 
T2.DAY_ID) OR (T1.CUSTOMER_ID = T3.CUSTOMER_ID AND T1.DAY_ID = T2.DAY_ID));
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join together A, B, and C using `LEFT JOIN`, and then retain records from A where a match occurred in *either* B or C.

```
INSERT INTO D
SELECT DISTINCT a.*      -- remove duplicate records
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b
    ON a.CUSTOMER_ID = b.CUSTOMER_ID AND a.DAY_ID = b.DAY_ID
LEFT JOIN tableC c
    ON a.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID AND a.DAY_ID = c.DAY_ID
WHERE b.CUSTOMER_ID IS NOT NULL OR    -- retain records where either
      c.CUSTOMER_ID IS NOT NULL       -- condition matches
```

If the D table is not already created, then create it using the same definition as for table A.

Comment: Mind giving some explanation to each step/term you're using? I'm not really familiar with the language.

Comment: Would I use "create" instead of "insert into" since my table is not already constructed?

Comment: @Stacksofoverflow Yes, go ahead and create table D if it be not already created.  Since it should have an identical structure to table A, you can just reuse the definition for table A.

Comment: ok thanks, do you know any good introductory texts in mysql/sql?

Comment: Believe it or not, I learned MySQL just by using it at work and also contributing to Stack Overflow.  That being said, an _excellent_ site which I use as a reference also has a good SQL tutorial, and you can find it here: [TechOnTheNet](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/index.php).

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate your help!